# После обновления Intellij начались глюки с работой android.support.v7.widget

Tags: обновление

Обновил ИДЕЕшку, запустил проект, а оно мне черкает все красным, что связанно с использованием android.support.v7.widget. Проект компилируется и работает, но работа превратилась в издевательство. В гредле проверил - библиотеки прописаны самые последние. Новый проект создается нормально, без ошибок. В чем причина может заключаться?
[image: Собственно что показывает]

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю как такое может быть, но проблему решил - убрал с зависимостей (dependencies) compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' и все заработало